# PHP putting the right row in the right html div

Tags: php, html

This one is going to be a bit hard to explain but I am going to try my best.

I have a database with a table called content with 3 columns, I’m trying to get the values as rows and put them in different `<div>’s`. here is what I wrote so far

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());

$contentDisplay = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 

    $content_id = $row["id"];
    $content_title= $row["title"];
    $content_text = $row["text"];

    $contentDisplay .= '<h1>'.$content_title.'</h1> <p>'.$content_text.'</p>' ."\n";        
} 

$row_cnt = $query->num_rows;
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

?>
```

The row count gives 4 rows which is correct amount of rows.

In my html I have `<?php echo $contentDisplay; ?>` which puts out all 4 rows after each other, but I need to show the first row in my first `<div>`, the second row in my second `<div>` and so forth. thanks in advance

**Update:** I forgot to say that I have my `<div>'s` in the html part with different styles. all i need is the first row in one `<div>` (like on top of the page) and second row in another `<div>` (like on the bottom of the page) :)

**Update2:** here is the html code

```
<div class="content-top">
    <section>
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="content-left">
    <section>
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="content-center">
    <section>
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="content-right">
    <section>
        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
    </section>
</div>
```

i want the first row to be displayed in `<div class="content-top">` the second row in `<div class="content-left">` the third row in `<div class="content-center">` and the fourth row in `<div class="content-right">`

Comment: Not sure I understand your update. There are only two rows, and they should go in two predefined `div`s? It might be helpful if you post that part of the code as well! :) Welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: you are correct sir. thank you :) see second update with html code.

Comment: What are you going to do when there are more than 4 rows returned by the query?

Comment: There are only 4rows in db and there wont any more added.

Comment: Alright. See edit in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die (mysqli_error());

$rows = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    $rows[] = '<h1>'.$row['title'].'</h1> <p>'.$row['text'].'</p>' . "\n";        
?>

<div class="content-top">
    <section>
        <?php echo $rows[0]; ?>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="content-left">
    <section>
        <?php echo $rows[1]; ?>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="content-center">
    <section>
        <?php echo $rows[2]; ?>
    </section>
</div>

<div class="content-right">
    <section>
        <?php echo $rows[3]; ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg thank you sir. it worked like a charm. ive been dueling with this for three days now. i do have a question :) what does `$rows = [];` do before while

Comment: `$rows = [];` declares `$rows` to be an empty array. Note that this syntax only works in PHP versions 5.4 and greater. In versions before this you will have to use `$rows = array();` `$rows[] = "value";` adds a value "to the end" of an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contentDisplay .= '<div><h1>'.$content_title.'</h1> <p>'.$content_text.'</p></div>' ."\n";
```

Just add divs for each row? :) This way, each row in the database will get a div.

Each row will be appended to the `$contentDisplay` variable, but since all you are doing is printing it, you can print the html directly.

I'm not sure why you are being downvoted, since you are asking a valid question with code that shows what you have tried so far.